# I'm trying to log in to Disney shop. I've tried many different selectors but none of them seem to be working. Any help or tips?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, selector

Here is my code; it basically goes to the page, clicks the side navigation bar, clicks sign in and then waits for the email and password elements.

Problem is they aren't working.

await page.goto('https://www.shopdisney.com/');

```
await page.waitForSelector('body > div.page > header > nav > div > div.layout--maxWidth > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.float-left > button')
await page.click('body > div.page > header > nav > div > div.layout--maxWidth > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.float-left > button')

await page.waitForSelector('#sg-navbar-collapse > div > div > nav > div.close-menu.clearfix.d-inline-block.d-lg-none > div.user.usercontainer > div > button.signin-or-signupbutton')
await page.click('#sg-navbar-collapse > div > div > nav > div.close-menu.clearfix.d-inline-block.d-lg-none > div.user.usercontainer > div > button.signin-or-signupbutton')

await page.waitFor(5000)

let selector = '#did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div:nth-child(1)'
await page.$eval(selector, elem => elem.click());

await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]')
await page.focus('input[type="email"]')
await page.keyboard.type('supreme@gmail.com', {delay: 100})

await page.waitForSelector('#did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div:nth-child(2) > div > label > span.input-wrapper > input')
await page.focus('#did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div:nth-child(2) > div > label > span.input-wrapper > input')
await page.keyboard.type('supreme123', {delay: 100})

await page.waitForSelector('#did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div.btn-group.touch-print-btn-group-wrapper > button')
await page.click('#did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div.btn-group.touch-print-btn-group-wrapper > button')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my version of the site, this selector:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('body > div.page > header > nav > div > div.layout--maxWidth > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.float-left > button')
```

Points to a element only enable in the mobile version, more precise, the hamburger menu.
Maybe you need to point to `user.user__container` selector.

What screen size use in `puppeteer.browser`?
Can you send the browser configuration? That because the screen size used by puppeteer change the available selectors, according the media queries of the site.